# Why smtpd_recipient_limit and other email related options in postfix does not work?

Tags: email, unix, smtp, postfix-mta

I have a server that runs on apache, and I am sending emails from that server. I want to set the number of recipients that each outgoing email can send to. I am following [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_connection_count_limit) tutorial and [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_connection_count_limit) manual - it seems to be as easy as adding `smtpd_recipient_limit=2` to `master.cf` like below, reloading postfix, and running a test with 3 recipients. Each recipients still get email, with no error messages in `/var/log/syslog` file below. What is missing?

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# limit number of emails that can be send. Each outgoing mail are seperated by 
# 1 second delay. Number of recepients of each message is limited to 10.
#smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
#smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
#smtpd_client_message_rate_limit=2
smtpd_recipient_limit=2
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit=0

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = xxx
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
# (sorry have to smear out the domain name)
mydestination = xxx, localhost.xxx, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

#Added 

home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Log file below

```
Apr 10 22:35:54 xxx postfix/pickup[7448]: 16151400BC: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Apr 10 22:35:54 xxx postfix/cleanup[7455]: 16151400BC: message-id=<597dd15203e984495188a846c186772e@xxx>
Apr 10 22:35:54 xxx postfix/qmgr[7447]: 16151400BC: from=<www-data@xxx>, size=674, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Apr 10 22:35:55 xxx postfix/smtp[7457]: 16151400BC: to=<yyy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.01/0/0.15/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1397183738 v62si6606269yhp.5 - gsmtp)
Apr 10 22:35:55 xxx postfix/smtp[7457]: 16151400BC: to=<zzz@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.01/0/0.15/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1397183738 v62si6606269yhp.5 - gsmtp)
Apr 10 22:35:55 xxx postfix/smtp[7457]: 16151400BC: to=<ttt@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.196.27]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.01/0/0.15/1.4, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1397183738 v62si6606269yhp.5 - gsmtp)
Apr 10 22:35:55 xxx postfix/qmgr[7447]: 16151400BC: removed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It is because `smtpd_recipient_limit` only apply to the mails received by `smtpd` daemon through an `SMTP` transaction. The mails submitted using `sendmail` command is queued in `maildrop` queue by `postdrop` command, which is picked up by `pickup` and fed to `cleanup` directly.
- You can't restrict recipient count for the mails submitted through `sendmail` command.

The only solution to this problem is force your applications to send mail only through `smtp` transaction.

Comment: regarding smtp and localhost, maybe this helps. https://serverfault.com/questions/641885/postfix-is-not-rejecting-recipients-addresses-when-mailx-is-used/641893#641893

regarding recipient limit. looks like you only change the way postfix creates copies of emails not the way emails are accepted

Answer (score 0):

You need to use smtp_destination_recipient_limit instead.