# How to limit number of recipients for outgoing mail using Postfix sendmail?

Tags: email, sendmail, postfix-mta

The basic problem is that I wish to limit number of recipients for outgoing mail using Postfix sendmail. I added `default_recipient_limit=2` and `default_destination_limit=2` to `main.cf` and reload postfix, but testing it by sending more than 2 emails fails.

There is a response to a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003276/why-smtpd-recipient-limit-and-other-email-related-options-in-postfix-does-not-wo) that says "You can't restrict recipient count for the mails submitted through sendmail command". I suppose this is referring to any application that invokes `/usr/sbin/sendmail` installed by Postfix. I couldn't confirm this in Postfix documentation or on Google. Can someone verify, and explain why it is (or not) possible to limit number of outgoing recipients on Postfix sendmail? More generally, what quotas or options can be configured with Postfix sendmail?

Comment: Do you want to control the number of recipients in a single mail or Do you want to limit the number of mails a user can receive in a time frame?

Comment: I want to control the number of recipients in a single mail. How to do that?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/23003276/2136319

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit it in the sendmail command. Only way would be to write a wrapper around the command.